# Detect recursive method calls at run time in byte code using ASM (5.x): howto?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

The problem is as follows; the method, in Java code, is:

```
Rule foo()
{
    return sequence(foo(), x());
}
```

This will provoke a parsing loop which of course should be avoided; however, *this* is legal:

```
Rule foo()
{
    return sequence(x(), foo());
}
```

Now, somewhere else in the code I do have access to a `RuleMethod`, which is a class extending `MethodNode`, and therefore I do have access to the following information:

- `ruleMethod.name`: `foo`; (defined in `MethodNode`)
- `ruleMethod.desc`: `()Lorg/parboiled/Rule;` (defined in `MethodNode`)
- `ruleMethod.ownerClass`: `com.github.fge.grappa.experiments.SelfReferringRule.MyParser` (defined in `RuleMethod`

And the bytecode of the first code extract above is as follows:

```
Method 'foo':
 0    L0
 1     ALOAD 0
 2     ALOAD 0
 3     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.foo ()Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
 4     ALOAD 0
 5     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.x ()Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
 6     ICONST_0
 7     ANEWARRAY java/lang/Object
 8     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.sequence (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
 9     ARETURN
10    L1
```

Which means I have each and every information available to me to be able to spot, at least in the bytecode above, that `foo()` is **the first argument** of the `sequence()` invocation, since the constructor accepts three arguments and there are three elements on the stack.

But of course I can't "eye inspect" at runtime. Therefore I need a way to do this...

It looks like what I need is a `MethodVisitor` and somewhat `visitInsn()`, then see what arguments there are and detect appropriately...

But I don't have the slightest idea where to start; searching around on the net seems to only give examples of how to *modify* byte code, not detect such situations :/

Where do I start?

Answer (score 2):

Analysis is generally much easier using the [tree api](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/package-summary.html) as it allows you to easily backtrack and provides support for flow analysis.

If I understand your problem correctly, all you need to do (if all you wish to support is simple cases such as your example) is scan backwards from the call to sequence. As you know the code compiles what's on the stack must be valid, so just count back three method calls / field gets / etc.

If you want to support more complex scenarios where the inputs are assigned to variables by branch statements you will need some sort of flow analysis.

Comment: Well, yeah, there will be variable assignment etc etc but then I'd like to be able to detect simple cases such as this to start with :p

Answer (score 0):

Create a `MethodVistor` and while you are in [visitCode()](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitCode()) of the method `foo()` look for [visitMethodInsn()](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitMethodInsn(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) and if the `name` argument in the `visitMethodInsn()` is `foo` you know that you have a recursive call to the method.

In your bytecode listing you have three `INVOKEVIRTUAL` instructions, these instructions are visited in order by the `visitMethodInsn()` function. If you want to check the sequence you can keep track of the order in which the method calls are made. You will see `foo()` first followed by `x()` and then finally `sequence()`.

```
3     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.foo ()Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
4     ALOAD 0
5     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.x ()Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
6     ICONST_0
7     ANEWARRAY java/lang/Object
8     INVOKEVIRTUAL com/github/fge/grappa/experiments/SelfReferringRule$MyParser.sequence (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/parboiled/Rule;
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to detect if it is the _first_ argument to a method invocation. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you confirm that the sequence of calls is correct in the generated bytecode as shown by their INVOKEVIRTUAL instructions?  In that case you can just check which one is visited first by visitMethodInsn and figure out the sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this question?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your intention correctly, you want to detect direct left recursion, which parboiled cannot handle. However, left recursion can be handled:

In essence, the parser must detect a left recursion and fail there, but remember that a left recursion occured. When the rule which was used in a recursive way succeeds, the result is saved as "seed" and the parsing process is restarted at the original input position. This time, when the left recursion happens, the seed is used instead of failing. This process is repeated.

For explanation see http://www.vpri.org/pdf/tr2007002_packrat.pdf for the paper. The algorithm can easily be adapted to PEG parsers.

A parsing library similar to parboiled using this technique is https://github.com/ruediste/lambda-peg-parser

Comment: Hmm, interesting... I'll have a good look at your project! Note that I have forked parboiled in fact; I already have features which parboiled does not, but now the modification I want to bring in require bytecode analysis! Home [here](https://github.com/fge/grappa)